# Job Activity Monitor MS SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I've been using Job Activity Monitor on SQL Management Server to check history of a Job that failed. The message tells me that:

> Must declare scalar variable @i.

The thing is that the file I'm working on is a Stored Procedure and I've declared the variable properly at the start.

My question is:

Is there any way to find the exact line which is causing problem using the Job Activity monitor?

This is how its used in the stored procedure:

```
declare @i nvarchar(50), @j nvarchar
.
.
.
.
.
.

(Then used in a cursor like this)
set @i = 0
        EXEC sp_executesql

            @statement = @sql,

            @parameters = N'@i(50) nvarchar OUTPUT',

            @i = @i OUTPUT 

      IF @i >0 
.
.
```

Comment: Could you post the piece where you declare this variable?

Comment: @betelgeuce: just did.

Answer (score 1):

You must define @Parameters of sp_executesql in following format:

```
@parameters = N'@i nvarchar(50) OUTPUT'
```